# How do I invalidate the cache of an entity?

Tags: 8, caching

Is there any easy way to clear the cache for a custom entity?
I know there is an entry in the cache_entity-Table. If i manually delete it, everything is fine.
I tried doing the same as in `\Drupal\Core\Entity->invalidateTagsOnSave()` or `\Drupal\Core\Entity->invalidateTagsOnDelete()`. This does not seem to change anything.

Unfortunately I can't just load the entity and resave it in this situation.

Comment: Are you adding any cache tags or contexts or data to the entity itself?

Answer (score 16):

But you know the entity ID that you want to have invalidated?

Then use `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type_id)->resetCache([$id]);`

Comment: that works like charm, but why `Cache::invalidateTags($tags)` does not work?

Comment: because the entity storage doesn't use cache tags.

Comment: is it useful when we render result in blocks? cause not working for me

Comment: I found that you need to combine this statement with the statement below in order to fully reset cache: `\Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags($entity->getCacheTagsToInvalidate());`

Comment: @Berdir would clearing the cache for entity that's being edited cause any issues? or that's only for the form cache?

Answer (score 6):

To invalidate a cache you should use the Drupal cache invalidator service : `cache_tags.invalidator`.

### Static call

```php
// Invalide a Node cache.
\Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags(['node:5']);
// Invalidate a custom entity cache.
\Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags(['custom_entity:5']);
// Invalidate a custom cache tag.
\Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags(['thing:identifier']);
```

### Dependency injection call

my_module.services.yml

```yml
services:
  hello.service:
    class: \Drupal\my_module\Service\Hello
    arguments:
      - '@cache.default'
      - '@cache_tags.invalidator'
```

Hello.php

```php
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheTagsInvalidator;

class Hello {

 /**
   * Cache backend.
   *
   * @var Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface
   */
  protected $cacheBackend;

 /**
   * Cache tags invalidator.
   *
   * @var Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheTagsInvalidator
   */
  protected $cacheInvalidator;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(
    CacheBackendInterface $cacheBackend,
    CacheTagsInvalidator $cacheInvalidator
  ) {
    $this->cacheBackend = $cacheBackend;
    $this->cacheInvalidator = $cacheInvalidator;
  }
  
  /**
   * Function getting something from cache.
   */
  public function getSomething() {
    $cid = 'thing:identifier';
    $data = NULL;
    $cache = $this->cacheBackend->get($cid);

    if ($cache) {
      $data = $cache->data;
    }
    else {
      $data = my_module_complicated_calculation();
      $this->cacheBackend->set(
        $cid,               // Cache tag identifier.
        $data,              // Data to store in cache.
        Cache::PERMANENT,   // Save permanently.
        ['node:5', 'user:7']// Automatically invalidated if these entities are modified.
      );
    }

    return $data;
  }
  
  /**
   * Function invalidating a cache tag.
   */
  public function invalidateSomething() {
    $cid = 'thing:identifier';
    $this->cacheInvalidator->invalidateTags([$cid]);

    return;
  }
}
```

### Links

- [Cache.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21Cache.php/class/Cache/9.1.x)
- [Cache tags docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-tags)
- [Cacheability of render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/arrays/cacheability)
- [Cache context](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/contexts)
- [Cache max-age](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/max-age)

Answer (score 3):

In your custom entity you should override the function

```
public function getCacheTagsToInvalidate();
```

of the [EntityInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/interface/EntityInterface/8.2.x).

Then, to clear that entity's cache you simply call

```
\Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags($entity->getCacheTagsToInvalidate());
```

If you do not override getCacheTagsToInvalidate() the default implementation in entity.php should also work:

```
public function getCacheTagsToInvalidate() {
    if ($this->isNew()) {
      return [];
    }
    return [$this->entityTypeId . ':' . $this->id()];
  }
```

The tags[] is just the name plus the id.

Comment: Will this also invalidate the `{entity_type_id}_list` tag?

Comment: It's your custom entity. If your cache on the {entity_type_id}_list tag depends on a single instance, then add this tag to your getCacheTagsToInvalidate() return array.